# Remove FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS at runtime

Tags: java, android, flags, android-windowmanager, android-window

I have a `MainActivity` with lots of `Fragment`s and in one specific Fragment I want to draw behind system bar, so I'm applying at runtime the following flag :

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    }
```

What I want now is when user exits this `Fragment` and enters another to remove that flag so there's no content behind status bar. I tried passing null as arguments to `setFlags()` method but that's giving an error. I have searched for `remove()` or `unSet()` methods but none exists. So how should I remove that flag for another `Fragment` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
```

---

`FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS` [got deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS) with following suggestion:

> Use [`Window#setStatusBarColor(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window#setStatusBarColor(int)) with a half-translucent color instead.

Having declared a color with hex value `#6F000000`, then in code:

```
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.my_color))
```

Comment: FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS code is deprecated, do you have any updated answer

Comment: FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS code is deprecated, am also looking for same